# computer configuration for connecting eth 50 or more nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, configuration

I'd like to rent a server to run eth client ,but I am not sure what the computer configuration should be?In my local pc ,I can only connect  less than 10 nodes and failed in sync.If I want to connect 50 or more nodes ,what the computer configuration should be ?8vCPu,500G SSD? Could you  please tell me your computer configuration and how many peers you connect,with synchronization time ? Thanks.,very much.

Comment: i don't think this SE is the place to ask this, but take into consideration that the blockchain has more than 150GB of data and running 50 full synchronized nodes would use up to 50 * 150GB of storage and each node would utilize 2 cores at least for perfect block processing. although u can use a 12 core to make 50 ndoes function, it won't be better than actually running 6 nodes only. RAM usage will be high as a minimum of 4 GB for a single node is the spec.

Comment: Why do you need 50 nodes? Will they sync to Ethereum mainnet? Unless it is explicitly required I'd try to use less nodes and share the blockchain data between them, same with other resources like RPC.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,I'm sorry that I didn't describe my problem clearly，I just want to rent a server to run one node.But I hope this node can connect 50 or more other nodes in Mainnet while I can only connect less than 10 nodes now  in my local pc,In this situation ,what kind of server configuration do I need to rent?So sorry for not making problem cleaarly.